# Updating Subscription status inside the database by using Stripe Webhooks

Tags: asp.net, stripe-payments

I am integrating the Stripe payment gateway with a subscription-based product website in ASP.NET Core 3.1.

I have a `Subscription` table in the SQL Server database. It has `expiration_date (datetime)` and `is_active (bit)` columns.

When the user subscribes to a product with a recurring price (per month), I add a current date + 1 month in the `expiration_date` column. I also insert `1` in `is_active` column to indicate that the subscription is active.

Once the first month of subscription has passed, I want the value of `is_active` flag of this subscription to become `0` in the database. Once the user has paid for the next month, the *Current Period* will update in stripe subscription and the value of `is_active` flag is to become `1` again.

For this purpose, I should use Stripe WebHooks. I want to get notified through webhook that a subscription period has ended. I am confused because, as per my understanding, webhook events for `customer.subscription` and `price` do not define something that gets triggered when the current period of subscription ends.

The image attached below indicates the current period and date of the next invoice. From documentation I have come to know that upcoming invoice events can be used. But I am not understanding how a webhook can be used with the upcoming invoice.

[image]

So, my questions are that which event fires at the end of the final day of one month of the subscription period and which one is fired when a new period is defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/subscription#subscription-renewal and https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#tracking.

When a subscription period ends, an invoice is created(`invoice.created`) to charge for the upcoming one. So when the cycle ends, you get a `customer.subscription.updated` event (because `current_period_start` and `current_period_end` are updated to the new period) and also an `invoice.created` event for the invoice that gets created to charge for this new period.

The way I would do it is

- listen to the `invoice.created` event
- when handling it, check that the `billing_reason` is `subscription_cycle` to differentiate from invoices created for other reasons https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-billing_reason
- retrive the referenced subscription from the invoice(https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/retrieve) and look at the `current_period_[start|end]` fields, which is the information you're looking for.

You could also listen to `customer.subscription.updated` and check if the reason for it updating is the billing period changing(by looking for `current_period_start` in the [`previous_attributes` of the Event](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object#event_object-data-previous_attributes) ); or do the same as above but via `invoice.paid` instead of `invoice.created` if you only care to update your system when a successful payment is made(thats what the https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#tracking approach does)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have gone through these links and some others on StackOverflow. I am making the status of subscription as `unpaid` if "Recurring Payment is Incomplete for 7 days" and if "The Invoice is past due by 30 days" from Stripe Dashboard (Settings section). Now would `unpaid` status of subscription be catchable from `customer.subscription.updated` event? To do it all with Invoice events doesn't seem right when subscription statuses are also being updated based on invoice events.

Comment: "would unpaid status of subscription be catchable from customer.subscription.updated event" yes, it would. So you can use the invoice events for the regular updating of your database for each billing period and the subscription.updated events for other state changes, yep(or combine them into one more complex handler possibly making use of `previous_attributes` as mentioned

Comment: Also I forgot to mention it but this is mostly all testable by creating subscriptions with short( a couple of minute) trial periods and waiting for them to end, as that generates a 'recurring' invoice and changes the billing cycle exactly like a regular monthly payment would, in terms of the webhook events it sends : https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing#trials